# Using find to exclude a directory and tar up everything else in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, find, gnu-coreutils

I have following in a directory:

dir1
dir2
file1
file2

I want to tar up everything except dir1

When I do:

```
find . -path '*dir1*' -prune -o -print
```

I don't see dir1 in the output ( as expected)

But when I do:

```
find . -path '*dir1*' -prune -o -exec tar -czvf documents.tgz  '{}' \+
```

I see that dir1 also gets tarred up in documents.tgz. Why ?

Answer (score 2):

If using "find" is not mandatory requirement, assuming "main_dir" as the parent directory name.

```
tar --exclude=main_dir/dir1 -cvzf tarred_file.gz main_dir/
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the current directory ('.') is passed as an argument to tar (though I get a warning about it, maybe you missed it?).

This works for me:

```
find . -path './dir1*' -prune -o -path './*' -exec tar -czvf documents.tar {} \+
```